# На вход программе подается натуральное число. Найдите количество цифр не больше 6 в числе

Tags: python, циклы

Помогите, пожалуйста, откорректировать код для Python. На вход программе подается натуральное число. Найдите количество цифр не больше 6 в числе. Для входного числа 896 не работает.

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
while (n > 0):
    count = count + 1
    n = n // 10
if count < 6:
    print(count)
```

Comment: Нужно считать цифры не больше 6, а ты считаешь общее количество цифр.

Comment: Благодарю, получилось!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
while(n>0):
    number = n % 10
    if(number < 6):
        count += 1
    n = n // 10
print(count)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Comment: 6 тоже не больше 6, поэтому надо <=